# What is the Tor browser's Adblock Plus default configuration on Tails OS?

Tags: configuration, tails, add-on

Just like to know just in case some would like to have adblock functionalities on their Tor browsers.

**Disclaimer:

Yes I know that adding this add-on will make a Tor browser appears more unique as it will add to the browser fingerprinting.**

**And it will require a constant look out for Tails OS update changelog for any Adblock plus updates and change the add-on's configuration accordingly. For such configuration updates might disrupt the fake Tails OS fingerprint.**

**For those who want to add such functionalities please be mindful of these.**

At least by using Adblock Plus instead of, for example, Ublock Origins might help to blend in with other Tails users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update: Tails no longer uses AdBlock Plus, it has moved to uBlock Origin. The information here is no longer valid.*

It's actually the one pulled from the debian repos, [`xul-ext-adblock-plus`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/xul-ext-adblock-plus), as per [`config/chroot_local-hooks/10-tbb`](https://git-tails.immerda.ch/tails/tree/config/chroot_local-hooks/10-tbb#n200)

[config/chroot_local-includes/etc/tor-browser/profile/preferences/0000tails.js](https://git-tails.immerda.ch/tails/tree/config/chroot_local-includes/etc/tor-browser/profile/preferences/0000tails.js) sets some further preferences too:

```
// Adblock Plus preferences
pref("extensions.adblockplus.correctTypos", false);
pref("extensions.adblockplus.currentVersion", "2.6.6");
pref("extensions.adblockplus.savestats", false);
pref("extensions.adblockplus.showinaddonbar", false);
pref("extensions.adblockplus.showintoolbar", false);
pref("extensions.adblockplus.subscriptions_autoupdate", false);
```

And the patterns that it uses are available in [`config/chroot_local-includes/etc/tor-browser/profile/adblockplus/patterns.ini`](https://git-tails.immerda.ch/tails/tree/config/chroot_local-includes/etc/tor-browser/profile/adblockplus/patterns.ini)

Comment: Great answer! Although do you mind explaining in your answer on how a Tor user with ABP configured like in Tails OS will still be distinguishable? What are the other fingerprintable factors that I have missed out?

Comment: @m894v5n74v539nm8 hmmm, it looks like the concrete example that I'd seen for detecting Tails vs Tor Browser was relying purely on adblock (https://github.com/jonaslejon/tor-fingerprint) and can't distinguish Tor Browser + ABP from Tails. While I can't rule out that there are distinguishers, I don't currently know what they are, I'm going to remove that from my answer till I can cite something solid.